# How to get function working with passed element from onClick in HTML <a>?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a simple HTML website that shows info from JavaScript file which takes data from API. Main function in JavaScript file is:

```
function mainFunction(param) {
    some code - if param1 then add something to HTML, if param2 then add something else, if paramN something else and so on, based on the data from API
}
```

What I'm struggling with is... **I want by default to load website with specific parameter** in function so it always shows specific content:

```
window.onload = function() {
    mainFunction(param1);
};
```

... unless I click a link:

```
<a id="someID" href="#" onClick="mainFunction(param2);">x</a>
```

on the website - then I want my content on page to change.

However, after clicking that link nothing changes. If I remove:

```
window.onload = function() {
    mainFunction(param1);
};
```

then page won't load with *default* content (blank page) but clicking the link surprisingly works and content do change to what I wanted. Therefore, I'm thinking maybe I can't overwrite parameter which is passed to function in `windows.onload`?

Ideally I would like to have say... 3 links in the footer of HTML page and each of them would have different `onClick` with specific parameter (eg. `param10`, `param11`, `param12`) to pass to `mainFunction()`. Clicking one of them will pass parameter to function and function will return & show specific content on the website. Clicking another will pass different parameter to function and function will return & show specific (but this time different) content on the website. Keep in mind that by default always `param1` should be loaded on page load because maybe links won't be clicked at all during page visit so change of content won't be necessary.

If there is some more explanation needed (or more code) please do tell me!

Comment: it doesn't have to do with onload, it's something else. my guess is that you set the innerHTML on something around the link that fires the change, thereby removing the event handler by re-creating the dom with fresh elements. re-bind the click handlers after updating the html, or use event delegation.

Comment: I don't think anything happens like that... How would you re-bind the click handlers?